# Whenever new files will get renamed it should come in one Folder,is it possible?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

**Below is the code for Renaming the existing Excel file,
The output is coming anywhere in the project but i want in a particular Folder the Output should come with current date and time using Selenium web driver/java**

```
package BrokenLink;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    public class newTestFile {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            CreateFileRenameExisting("PCPAutomation.xlsx");
```

**when trying to add the folder details getting this Exception-->C:\Users\skumari1\eclipse-workspace\AlarmTest\genericFiles\PCPAutomation.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)-->Not able to to give the Folder address**

```
        }

        //Rename an existing file and create a new file
        public static void CreateFileRenameExisting(String filename)
        {
            //get current project path
            String filePath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
            //create a new file
            File file=new File(filePath+"\\"+filename);
            try {
                if(!file.exists()) {
                    Workbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook();

                    FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream(filename);

                    wb1.write(fileOut1);

                    fileOut1.close();
                    //file.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("File is created");
                }
                else
                {
                    File backupFile=new File(filePath+"\\"+ Validatedate()  +  file.getName());
                    System.out.println("File already exist and backup file is created");
                    file.renameTo(backupFile);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

public static String Validatedate() {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH_mm_ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String date1= dateFormat.format(date);
            // System.out.println("Current date and time is " +date1);
             return date1;
        }
    }
```

****Kindly help me with the above code so that i can give the Folder address in the above code, Thank you in advance****

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the folder is not existing yet. For some it might be a bit counter-intuitive, but Java does not create the folder to place the new file into it. You must make sure, that the folder exists before placing the file into it, like:

```java
void writeToFile(File file) throws IOException {
    File folder = file.getParentFile();
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    //... create file and write into it
}
```

Also, `File::mkdirs` method returns `boolean`, so `false` if failed to create. For that reason I usually throw `IOException` manually:

```java
if (!folder.mkdirs()) throw new IOException("Failed to create folder: " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Can you please write this code with the Previous code because when i am doing it ,I am getting some errors.

Comment: @Sonamkumari I forgot to place the parenthesis `()` to the `mkdirs()` call in the second code part - fixed it now - otherwise seems functional for me. If you still have errors, let me know what it says.